# Nested Lists, Python from bash Output

Tags: python, regex, list

How do we create a nested list by taking off the terminal output ?

Ex: I am querying the terminal to get some output (In this case, it's related to Yarn)

```
import subprocess    
outputstring=subprocess.check_output("yarn application -list | grep " + user, shell=True)    
mylist = (re.split("[\t\n]+",outputstring))=
```

This produces a output on each line for each Job that's running on Yarn.
    Eg:

```
line1 = a,b,c,d,e
line2 = f,g,h,i,j
line3 = k,l,m,m,o
```

I am able to create a list off this output, but as a single list with all the words as comma separated values like

```
mylist = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o] using the regex above.
```

but need to create a list as below:

```
mylist = [[a,b,c,d,e], [f,g,h,i,j], [k,l,m,n,o]]
```

i.e:

```
mylist = [[line1],[line2],[line3]]
```

can anyone please suggest how to achieve this ?

Regex I am currently using is:

```
mylist = (re.split("[\t\n]+",outputstring))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this list comprehension:

```
a="""a,b,c,d,e
f,g,h,i,j
k,l,m,m,o"""
mylist=[e.split(",") for e in a.split("\n")]
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just do this?

```
my_list = [line1.split(','), line2.split(','), line3.split(',')]
```

or this

```
initial_list = []

initial_list.append(line1)
initial_list.append(line2)
initial_list.append(line3)

final_list = [x.split(',') for x in initial_list]
```

I know you surely have not only 3 lines, but if you can do ["a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k,l"] with your output, maybe you can do this as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using the [`map`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#map) function:

```
output = """a,b,c,d,e
f,g,h,i,j
k,l,m,m,o"""

output = list(map(lambda i: i.split(','), output.split('\n')))
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'], ['k', 'l', 'm', 'm', 'o']]
```